# Search for a "close point" efficiently

Tags: java, algorithm

I'm asking this because I'm sure there has been brought up before but not sure how to call it.
I need an efficient way to search and store some point in a metric space. Specifically, I need to find the weather at some points in space and time. I have an API to do that, but don't want to make another request if I have already queried in the past about a point a few inches away from the new point and a few seconds before it, as the weather there would be the same.

So when I receive a new point, I need to ask - do I have in the cache a point "close enough" (whose distance from the new point is a below a threshold)? 
 If I do - take the data associated with that point. Otherwise, cache the new point.
This can be done easily using a serial check but I'm interested in ways to do it more efficiently.

Thanks!

Comment: Your question is too broad; the best answer will depend on the specifics of your task.

Comment: you can simply use TreeMap with overwritten Comparator(), i.e. if two points are within some eps then return 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose your thresshold is `t`, you can split your search space to a grid,
with cells having width and height `t`.
Every cell will have a list of points that lie in it.

Now when given a new point, you compute which cell it falls into,
let this be the cell [i,j], you check this cell and all of its neigbors
(i.e. 9 cells altogether), whether they contain any points and if they do,
these are your candidates for closer-than-thresshold points.
You will now compute the distance of all of these.

Since the cells are `t` wide and `t` high, distance of all points
lying in any other cell is at least `t`.

You can store the grid cells in a TreeMap, with the comparator based on [i,j] pairs.
(you only store the cells which have at last one point in them).

Comment: I can't store the entire grid up front, since it's too large. So I need to follow the TreeMap idea. However, let's say I have a tree map with some points cached in it. I didn't understand, how do I now check if a certain point is near of one the points in the tree map(and if so what point is it)?

Comment: Nevermind, I slept on it and understood it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't you know. Going to a search engine called Google and using some time to string words together, you get [Nearest neighbor search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbor_search) as the first result. Who'da thunk it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe what you need is a [Voronoi diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram) built from your cache points.